# Translate path controller

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have the following path defined in my routing.yml:

```
path: '/department/{department_node}/qualifications/{qualification_id}'
```

I need to translate that route into other languages, for example into Spanish:

```
path: '/departamento/{department_node}/titulaciones/{qualification_id}'
```

**department_node** would be a "department" node

**qualification_id** would be a dynamic id from a web service

So the result should be:

```
en: /department/department-title/qualifications/99
es: /departamento/department-title/titulaciones/99
```

As the qualification_id is a dynamic value, I can't create an alias, as I would have many after a while and they would be out of date. Does anyone know any method of translating the routes in this case?

Comment: @Hudri is right, you can't translate a route. The language specific things are handled in path processing, for which [core aliasing](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21path_alias%21src%21PathProcessor%21AliasPathProcessor.php/class/AliasPathProcessor/9.0.x)  is not the only one way to do this, you could use a custom path processor to translate parts of the path. BTW I think the easiest way would be to move the dynamic part to a query parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes != URLs, you can't translate a route, you only can translate URL aliases.

One route has only one path, which - through optional wildcards - could match more than one URL. Because no single part in your desired URLs is stable, you can't do this with one route. (And AFAIK the first `/part/` of a route path must be constant too in Drupal, it cannot start with a wildcard.)

An URL alias is an optional, separate entity that matches an arbitrary URL to an existing route.

You either have to dynamically create/update URL aliases, or add new route only for the spanish translation. But it is allowed to reuse the same controller for multiple routes, so overhead would only be a single entry in a `routing.yml` file.

Comment: I understand, so if I want to add a new route for Spanish, I should also control the aliases, because otherwise I would get different results when using the language selector

Comment: Don't know your requirements, but in this case I guess I wouldn't use URL aliases at all. Making the controller language-aware is IMHO much simpler than constantly creating/updating URL aliases. You have got two routes, with two wildcards each, leading to one controller, who has to serve the proper entity in the proper language.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that when using the controllers, the department should be an id, and not the name, which is what I'm sending right now cause it's an alias

Comment: Yes, automatic entity upcasting only works with numeric IDs. But you also can implement custom logic in your controller and manually load the corresponding department node using the string/slug variable from the route. Something like `entityQuery->condition('field_foo', $variableNameFromRoute)`